# How to get the path of the uploaded file within the AppBundle?

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

We are using Autodesk Forge's Design Automation API. We have an AppBundle ready and we put an **.rfa** file into the same folder which contains the **.dll** file. When the AppBundle is unzipped on the Forge servers, which path can lead to our **.rfa** file? (how can we access it?) Our goal is to place the attached Family file's contents into the input file which is being uploaded with the API, and the result should be a new file which contains the additions from the file which we uploaded within the AppBundle. The process works when testing with Revit locally, but it doesn't work with the API. In the report we are retrieving it's obviously pointing out that the attached file cannot be found:

```
Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.FileNotFoundException: T:\Aces\Jobs\ced628d35ecf4412b68c024e2cec098b\something.rfa
```

On the code side, we are trying to access the .rfa file via this path:

```
static string currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
static string path_input =  currentDir+@"\something.rfa";
```

This seemed as a logical path, but as it turned out, it's not..
Is there a way to access the **.rfa** file inside the uploaded **AppBundle**?
I took a look at the [Restrictions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/restrictions/) but reading the file from the AppBundle is not mentioned as restricted or not approachable. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .NET assembly knows its own path. You can call [System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly) within it to find the current path of the dll. You can then compute the path of the `.rfa` file relative to the folder of the dll and use it / open it. Thus you should be able to open any file you package along with your addin in your `appbundle`.

You can simply modify your code to:

```cs
static string assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
static string assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);
static string path_input = assemblyDirectory+@"\something.rfa";
```

One thing to note however, is that you only have readonly access to files in `appbundle`. If your code relies on modifying these during execution, then you may simply copy the source `rfa` file to the current working folder and then work with the copied file instead.

Also see more details in [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/store-template-documents-appbundle) for similar ideas.

Answer (score 1):

We have a blog post on how you can either pass in the **app bundle** path in the `commandLine` parameter or find the path via the location of the **add-in** dll:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/store-template-documents-appbundle